# Bands of blank or improperly rendered scan lines using offscreen rendering with Frame Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl, graphics, device-driver

I am doing offscreen tiled rendering of very large output images using FBOs. In order to have the best performance, I am trying to create the largest FBO (and thus tile size) that I can. To that end, I am using GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_EXT to retrieve the maximum possible size and then reducing it so that my FBO does not fill more than 1/16'th of the available VRAM.

Doing this seems to ensure that my renderer never fails on an out of memory or incomplete FBO error; however, with large enough FBOs (2002x1202 in one simple test case), I sometimes get a strange result. On my Quadro 8600M as well as on another Quadro FX 1700, I'll see bands of scan-lines in which either nothing is rendered or a few pixels are rendered of the wrong color. This does not happen if I constrain the size of the FBO to something smaller such as 500x500.

Does this ring any bells for anyone? I'm kind of stumped.

(I am using Windows XP Professional SP3)

Comment: A note to anyone who comes across this: It ended up being a bug in the NVidia drivers. I had to collaborate for a while with them to narrow it, but they say they've fixed it now. I implemented a work-around, and I don't know when the fix will actually be out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the workaround you used, and the bug in particular?

Comment: The bug was to do with their implementation of glClear() on stencil buffers. I worked around it by drawing a full-screen quad.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver "bug".

I'd try to reproduce on other hardware (ATI) if at all possible. Also try different driver versions on the Quadro hardware.

Also check your GL error codes, or run through something like [glDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com/products.php).